# Loopback custom password validation

Tags: validation, model, loopback

very simple question: if I try to validate a password in a User model it seems I can only validate the already encrypted password?
So for example if I use

```
 Customer.validatesLengthOf('password', { min: 8, message: 'Too short' })
```

Then the encrypted password is checked (which is always longer than 8 characters), so no good... If I try to use a custom validation, how can I get access to the original password (the original req.body.password basically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, no answer so what I'm doing is using a remote hook to get access to the original plain password and that'll do for now.

```
var plainPwd
Customer.beforeRemote( 'create', function (ctx, inst, next) {
    plainPwd = ctx.req.body.password
    next()
})
```

Then I can use it in a custom validation:

```
Customer.validate( 'password', function (err, res) {
    const pattern = new RegExp(/some-regex/)
    if (plainPwd && ! pattern.test( plainPwd )) err()
}, { message: 'Invalid format' })
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT (August 20, 2019): I am unsure if this is still an issue in the latest loopback releases.

In fact, this is a [known problem](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/251) in loopback. The [tacitly approved](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/251#issuecomment-312066721) solution is to [override the `<UserModel>.validatePassword()` method with your own](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/251#issuecomment-271518777). YMMV.

> akapaul commented on Jan 10, 2017 •
>
> I've found another way to do this. In common model User there is a
>   method called validatePassword. If we extend our UserModel from User,
>   we can redefine this method in JS, like following:
>
> ```js
> var g = require('loopback/lib/globalize');
>
> module.exports = function(UserModel) {
>   UserModel.validatePassword = function(plain) {
>     var err,
>         passwordProperties = UserModel.definition.properties.password;
>
>     if (plain.length > passwordProperties.max) {
>       err = new Error (g.f('Password too long: %s (maximum %d symbols)', plain, passwordProperties.max));
>       err.code = 'PASSWORD_TOO_LONG';
>     } else if (plain.length < passwordProperties.min) {
>       err = new Error(g.f('Password too short: %s (minimum %d symbols)', plain, passwordProperties.min));
>       err.code = 'PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT';
>     } else if(!(new RegExp(passwordProperties.pattern, 'g').test(plain))) {
>       err =  new Error(g.f('Invalid password: %s (symbols and numbers are allowed)', plain));
>       err.code = 'INVALID_PASSWORD';
>     } else {
>       return true;
>     }
>     err.statusCode = 422;
>     throw err;
>   };
> };
> ```
>
> This works for me. I don't think that g (globalize) object is required
>   here, but I added this, just in case. Also, I've added my validator
>   options in JSON definition of UserModel, because of Loopback docs

For using the above code, one would put their validation rules in the model's `.json` definition like so (see `max`, `min`, and `pattern` under `properties.password`):

```json
{
  "name": "UserModel",
  "base": "User",
  ...
  "properties": {
    ...
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      ...
      "max": 50,
      "min": 8,
      "pattern": "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])^.*$"
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of specifying validator settings that should work @akapaul's code example.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess the above answer is quite novel and obviously is accepted, but If you want a real easy solution with just some basic validations done and not much code then [loopback-mixin-complexity](https://github.com/AbdoulNdiaye/loopback-mixin-complexity) is the solution for you.

If you don't want to create another dependency then you can go ahead with a custom [mixin](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Defining-mixins.html), that you can add into your user model or any other model where you need some kind of validation and it would do the validation for you.

Here's a sample code for how to create such mixin

```
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  'use strict';
  Model.observe('before save', function event(ctx, next) { //Observe any insert/update event on Model
    if (ctx.instance) {
      if(!yourValidatorFn(ctx.instance.password) )
         next('password not valid');
      else 
        next();
    } 
    else {
      if(!yourValidatorFn(ctx.data.password) )
         next('password not valid');
      else 
        next();
    }
  });
};
```